# How to detect broken PL/SQL in Apex Application?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

We have several Apex 19.2 applications.

Inside each app there is PL/SQL everywhere: Application Processes, Pages Processes, Conditions, Item Sources, etc.

Sometimes when we change something in the database, let's say renaming a table, we would like to make sure no PL/SQL code is broken inside any of the applications.

Currently, whenever we rename an object, we search inside the apps using the following queries, for this object and make sure the pieces of code are working (or use the workspace search feature):

```
    select * from apex_application_computations where application_id = 1200;
    select * from APEX_APPLICATION_PAGE_COMP where application_id = 1200;
    select * from APEX_APPLICATION_PAGE_PROC where application_id = 1200; 
    select * from APEX_APPLICATION_PAGE_VAL where application_id = 1200;
    select * from APEX_APPLICATION_PAGE_BRANCHES where application_id = 1200;
    select * from apex_application_page_items where application_id = 1200;
    select * from APEX_APPLICATION_PAGE_REGIONS where application_id = 1200;
```

This method works but has its limitations. For example, in case we miss another table we have to look into, then the code will be broken.

Another limitation of this method is that sometimes the change has more complex consequences. For example, let's say we renamed a table, the same table itself is not used directly in any application, but used by a view which is used in the applications. In this case, this method won't work and we will end up with broken code.

For database objects we use the following query which works very well:

```
SELECT object_type, object_name FROM user_objects WHERE status = 'INVALID'
```

So we were wondering if there is something equivalent that works for code inside the applications.

How can we spot immediately which piece of code in the applications is broken following a change in the database?

Comment: Hi Thomas, not directly helping on the issue at hand, but is it possible for you to create procedures and functions on database backend side and just call/trigger them from APEX? This way you would probably much faster run into specific compiling issues when trying to change things that affect your PL/SQL codes long term?
 [EDIT: also note there is "Your App"--> Utilities --> Advisor which can perform automated checks. One of these is "Is Valid SQL or PL/SQL Code" and may help.]

Comment: @doomi you are right ! The best way to do it is to put as much plsql code as possible in packages/functions/procedures in the database. But still sometimes a change in function, let's say adding a new argument, may cause issues in the application. Any way ["Your App"--> Utilities --> Advisor] is EXACTLY what I was looking for. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is given by @Doomi : "Your App"--> Utilities --> Advisor
and check for Valid/Invalid SQL or PL/SQL Code

Thanks.